# simplexml_load_string returns values with no tags

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have xml file and i'm fetching it with curl and i get

```
string(3781) "
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <!--
        Generated by e-racuni.com

        Release number: 791.2
        Release date: 10.09.2019
        Request URL: /WebServicesHR/API
    -->

<response status="ok">
    <SalesInvoice>
        <advanceInvoicesRef></advanceInvoicesRef>
        <amountAlreadyPaid>-90</amountAlreadyPaid>
        <amountLeftToBePaid>0</amountLeftToBePaid>
        <bankAccountNumber>HR5623600001101883472</bankAccountNumber>
        <businessUnit>0000</businessUnit>
        <businessYear>2019</businessYear>
        <buyerCountry>HR</buyerCountry>
        <buyerName></buyerName>
        <buyerVatRegistration>Unknown</buyerVatRegistration>
        <city>Zagreb</city>
    </SalesInvoice>
</response>
"
```

I tried to use simplexml_load_string but I get only values like this

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) { [0]=> string(2869) " -90 0 
HR5623600001101883472 0000 2019 HR Unknown Zagreb 

  $url = "http://www.elektroprofi.hr/api/demo.php";

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,3);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $response = simplexml_load_string($result);

  var_dump($response);
```

if anyone can help me, im new in this and it's all confuzing , im expecting to get something like [city] => zagreb , [date] => 2019-02-04

Comment: In general, beware of using `var_dump` with `SimpleXMLElement` objects; they implement a lot of "magic" that doesn't show up well with generic debug functions. However in this case, I can't reproduce your problem: given the string above (without the extra whitespace at the start) I get a view of all the elements and attributes: https://3v4l.org/3ZI4W

Comment: i somehow resolved the problem,  $response = new SimpleXMLElement(simplexml_load_string($curl_data)), after that code i finally get xml object , i really dont know how and why

Comment: It sounds like what you have is XML wrapped inside XML: your solution is basically `parseXml(parseXml($response))` because `new SimpleXMLElement` and `simplexml_load_string` are just different ways of writing the same thing.